# how to find the higher/lower number between two in ASM, through arithmetic operations and logic gates only

Tags: assembly

that is the question I got:
Write a piece of code that receives two variables num1 and num2 and unconditionally, only with the help of arithmetic operations, puts the number with the larger value into a variable named big and the smaller one into small.

I only just recently started learning assembly, any help?

I thought using something like average of sum & difference will do it, but I just could not get it to work.
From tips and hints I got it seems like the solution is much simpler with the help of boolean algebra (aka logic gates). My mind could not work anything out, perhaps your's can.

Comment: You can do boolean algebra in most any language, so  you don't have to think in assembly for this.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, the question is specifically form assembly (my teach gave me it as bonus for the homework)

Comment: You're trying to develop an algorithm, and, my point is that you don't have to think in assembly to work boolean algebra.  Once you know what you're doing you can write it in assembly.  Assembly is so much easier when you already know what you want the code to do.

Comment: OK, I  get you're point, I tried approaching it in different ways buts could not come up with a solution, could you help?

Comment: There's not enough information here to offer you a solution, though even if there was we wouldn't do that without you also sharing your work and showing where you're stuck.  The phrase "*only ... arithmetic opreations*" is too vague.  Are you allowed loops, conditions, etc..?  Are the variables signed or unsigned?  What have you tried?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/227418/547981). Be sure to use signed shift.

Comment: `cmp` and `cmovl` could be considered arithmetic and logic.  (Or `sub` and `cmov`).  CMOV isn't a single boolean operation, it's a select controlled by FLAGS, so internally it's equivalent to multiple boolean ops.